# Can I yield item in Spider Idle

Tags: python, scrapy

I need to yield saved items in spider Idle. Is it possible?

```
def spider_idle(self, spider):
    for item in self.saved_items:
        yield item
```

Not working!

Comment: Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

spider_idle is a signal to perform some action when the spider is in idle condition. 
For more information refer here : https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#spider-idle

You cannot yield the item in spiders_close as all the results will go to parse method.